# Using ArrayForumla to sum columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I can't get my Array Formula to automatically copy down my formula.

I've tried various iterations, but it just seems to copy down the same value.

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong, please?

Example here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vN2alv94yhdXI01NdDpoziRuQq938lu-_MoFYDadxh4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B3:B), C3:C+D3:D+E3:E, ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Brilliant - This works and I understand the logic behind this. 
Don't quite understand how MMULT version works - 
Thank you - i can use this example to help me solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY({B3:E}, "select Col2+Col3+Col4 label Col2+Col3+Col4''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi thanks for the input - but i'm trying to get Array Formula to work, because i want it to copy down automatically, if I was to add additional rows of data

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(INDIRECT("C3:E"&COUNTA(B3:B)+2), (TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C3:E3)^0))))
```

[image: 0]